# Iterating through nested list for appending web scrape result

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, iteration

I am trying to iterate through the list "company", to launch a google search for each element of them, scrape the result, and append the google result to each of them.

the company variable is as such, comprised of 895 lists

`company = [['24/7 CUSTOMER Private Limited'], ['3 K TECHNOLOGIES Limited'], ['3I INFOTECH B P O Limited'], ['3I INFOTECH CONSULTANCY SERVICES Limited'], ['3I INFOTECH Limited'], ['4D CORPORATION Private Limited'], ['8K MILES SOFTWARE SERVICES Limited'], ['A B P Private Limited']...]]`

and I would like the output to be

`[['24/7 CUSTOMER Private Limited', New Dehli India], ['3 K TECHNOLOGIES Limited', Palo Alto United States], ['3I INFOTECH B P O Limited', New Dehli India], ['3I INFOTECH CONSULTANCY SERVICES Limited', New York United States], ['3I INFOTECH Limited', New York United States], ['4D CORPORATION Private Limited', Mumbai India], ['8K MILES SOFTWARE SERVICES Limited', New Dehli India ], ['A B P Private Limited', New Dehli India]...]]`

This is the function that takes company name as an parameter and ouputs its scraping result

```
def scrape(row):
        
    query = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+ row + " headquarters"
    r = requests.get(query)   
    html_doc = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    snippett = re.sub(cleanr, '', str(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd'})[0]))
    
    return snippett
```

Then calling the function by iterating trough the company's lists and appending the results

```
for lst in company():
    for row in lst():    
        hq_result = scrape(row)
        row.append(hq_result)
```

This error appears:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Seems like `soup.find_all()` returns empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. If you are just going to grab the first element (index 0) of the `<div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd">`, just use `.find()` in stead of `f.ind_all()`, as it will just return the first node.
2. No need to use regex to get the the text/content. Just use BeautfulSoup method of `.text`
3. The class attribute of `BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd` appears to be dynamic. It likely won't be present in each query you make to google search. Either, change it so it is dynamic (adjusts accordingly) or use google api to get search results.
4. My last point (and most importantly) is google is sophisticated enough to recognize an automated process/robot scraping. So you will likely eventually get a response of

`Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot.`

So again, I'd suggest seeking out the method of api.